# Wordpress - Elementor pro nav align issue

Tags: wordpress, elementor

if anyone could help that would be much appricated. in the elementor editor it is all aligned and fine. but as soon as i update and view live version the menu looks like this.

when i hover over policies it appears like this. i have not had an issue before as it has always aligned under the dropdown in the correct position. also the text is aligned to the right and will not change to the left.

[image: or]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a link to the live page to check the code?
What do you mean with "live view" - are you working with some kind of staging/deployment tool?
Maybe it's a cache problem of either your browser or the server, did you try to clear them? Did you try to view the page still logged into WordPress and not logged in, does that make a difference?